# What is the difference between the 2-clause and 3-clause BSD license?

Tags: bsd

The only difference between the text of the [3-Clause BSD License](https://opensource.org/licenses/BSD-3-Clause) and the [2-Clause BSD License](https://opensource.org/licenses/BSD-2-Clause) is that the 3-Clause BSD License has this additional clause:

> 3. Neither the name of the copyright holder nor the names of its contributors may be used to endorse or promote products derived from this software without specific prior written permission.

What is the practical effect of this clause that makes the BSD 3-Clause different from BSD 2-Clause? Isn't it the case that people have to get permission to use another person's name to endorse a software, even in the absence of clause 3 of the BSD 3-Clause License? Does the third clause actually do anything?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [BSD-3, third clause clarification](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/12896/bsd-3-third-clause-clarification)

Comment: Related: [What's "no longer necessary" about parts of BSD-3?](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/2026/whats-no-longer-necessary-about-parts-of-bsd-3)